Validation ErrorTemplate shows on `ContentControl` instead of `TextBox`
Problem
I'm trying to generate visual feedback on the result of validating a TextBox input control with the following requirements:

A red box is displayed around the textbox border
Any error messages are displayed just below the textbox

The related validation code seems to be working: the function that performs validation is running, the error messages are accumulated, and OnErrorsChanged is being invoked and WPF is doing ... something... a red box appears around my entire UserControl.
After reading many related SO questions/answers and considering the fact that a red box is being drawn, my initial instinct was that this is related to adorner placement. However, I have tried placing AdornerDecorator at every layer with no effect. I also have checked at runtime if the textbox controls have an adorner layer accessible to them, and they do. It is being created from the ContentControl hosting my view (View1.xaml). This seems to explain why I'm seeing a red box around the entire ContentControl, but I'm confused as to why the TextBox's Validation.ErrorTemplate is not controlling the placement of the adorner.

Control layout

View1.xaml

UserControl

Grid

GroupBox

StackPanel (vertical layout)

StackPanel (horizontal layout - repeated for all textbox controls)

Label
Textbox (validated control - ErrorTemplate here)













Code
View1.xaml
<UserControl x:Class="View1"
             ....namespaces....
             xmlns:Fluent="urn:fluent-ribbon"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.ViewModel"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.View"
             Name="MyView1"
             DataContext="{StaticResource g_MainWindowViewModel}"
             Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}">
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <ContentControl Name="NewSessionFormContentControl" 
                    Content="{Binding m_SessionFormViewModel}" 
                    DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
</DockPanel>

With a ControlTemplate taken from BionicCode's answer here:
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationErrorTemplate">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="AdornedElement"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Background="White" 
            BorderBrush="Red" 
            Padding="4"
            BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent}" 
                            Foreground="Red"
                            DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>

Here is a sample input control to be validated in this view:
<TextBox Name="Name1"
        Width="350" 
        Validation.ErrorTemplate="{DynamicResource ValidationErrorTemplate}"
        Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWayToSource, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>


This is not related to the AdornerDecorator. It doesn't matter what element  hosts the AdornerLayer. The binding engine will simply add an Adorner to the first parent AdornerLayer it finds in the current visual tree. This Adorner renders the Validation.ErrorTemplate value. The Adorner is adorning the actual element that has a target property of which the Binding reports a validation error (TextBox.Text). Validation error rendering is binding based. Each individual Binding tracks and manages its own validation errors. The binding engine by default always adorns the binding target.

You would have to set the Validation.ValidationAdornerSite property to force the binding engine to adorn a different element. For example, a UserControl is composed of multiple controls where each is bound to a data source. And if one of these bindings fails to pass validation you want the UserControl to appear as invalid and to provide the visual error feedback. The control author would then set Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteFor on the child to reference the parent UserControl. The binding engine will now pick the Validation.ValidationAdornerSite value as the adorned element.

Long story short. By default, the TextBox would be adorned with the Validation.ErrorTemplate. All your adorner related code is not required and must be removed as the adorners are completely managed by the binding engine.

The issue you are describing is usually the result of the child control binding to a property on the parent UserControl while this property of the UserControl binds to the actual data source (this would be proper control design). If this is not the case for example because your child controls all bind directly to the DataContext, then it would be nice if you could post the XAML context of the TextBox and how the UserControl is used/configured. A little more context to enable a code review. This way we can find out what overrides the default behavior.

The view model code is also irrelevant in this case. The validation itself is working properly. Only the rendering of the error template is not as desired. The view model (or the INotifyDataErrorInfo implementation in general) can't have any influence on the rendering site. The issue must be related to the binding target (the UserControl and the TextBox). So, if the TextBox is not binding as follows: TextBox ==> UserControl ==> data source then please post the view related context. Otherwise, please let me know that your binding path matches the pattern and I will directly post a fix.

Thanks for the detailed comments! The TextBox to be validated is bound directly to the data source (my original question has a sample TextBox from my view) via OneWayToSource. I will update the question with more code from the view as well as some details on the data flow.

Thanks for updating the question. The original binding only showed {Binding Name}, so I wasn't sure if Name is a property defined by the UserControl that is just named the same as the view model property. This wouldn't be uncommon. So, I asked. In general, you don't use dependency injection to assign view model instances to views.  Usually, you would have an e.g. MainViewModel which exposes several child view model classes. You probably inject the MainViewModel into the MainWindow. From there it's all XAML referencing.

You can then reference the MainViewModel to assign a more specialized DataContext to individual controls or scopes of controls - but always externally. For example, in your case the assignment of the DataContext should look as follows: Set externally! <Window  DataContext="{StaticResource g_MainWindowViewModel}"> <View1 DataContext="{Binding m_ViewModel}" /> </Window>. Besides that, you would make use of DataContext inheritance.

And your control would not explicitly reference the current DataContext. It's not critical unless you want your controls to be reusable. To be reusable they need to be DataContext or view model agnostic (internally). A control would request all required data by exposing dependency properties that the client then externally binds to the DataContext. The exact way you set the ItemsSource property of a ListBox. ListBox does not directly bind to the DataContext internally. Instead, it binds to the ItemsSource property.

Thank you very much for the additional information you have provided. I'm sorry to say that it is not enough to reproduce the behavior. From what you have posted the behavior should be the way you expect it: a red border around the TextBox and not the View1 control. Would you mind creating a minimal reproducible example? Maybe you could start with a blank project and then add code until you are able to reproduce the behavior. No extras, just the bare minimum. Thank you!

I also realized that your TextBox Binding is OneWayToSource. This shouldn't work exactly the way you want it to: OneWayToSource will trigger the validation as expected but it will not trigger the view to show the visual error feedback. This is because the error related information is assigned to the binding target via attached properties. But the target element will only get updated when the binding engine updates it - which is only possible in a TwoWay, OneWay or OneTime binding.

OneWay and OneTime are not updating the source (to trigger the data validation) so they are disqualified. Only TwoWay is left. To get binding validation the binding must be TwoWay or OneWayToSource. To get error feedback the binding must be TwoWay. Despite that, you somehow managed to show error feedback, although on the wrong control. That's why I think that the issue could be related to the way you are explicitly updating the binding. However, having your minimal reproducible example will bring clarity.

I've added MRE to the original question, even though I fear it has bloated this page beyond readability.

UpdateSourceTrigger=Expliciton all validated controls just to trigger validation explicitelly is a mistake. Your viewmodel should have a method that will validate all properties and notifies when there are errors

@Liero I originally wanted to update on field change (in the property setter for each data item bound to a textbox), but this triggered validation when the backing viewmodel data was instantiated, so I wasn't sure how to avoid that.

Thanks for providing more details. I wouldn't consider this a minmal reproducible example. It contains a lot of noise. All the 3rd party dependencies for example. I'm pretty sure the behavior persists if you remove this dependency/redundant code. But it helps. I will review it and come back to post a solution.

Your code has several flaws and it does not honor certain details of the binding engine's validation behavior. I also have some suggestions to make that should improve your overall code.
1 Missing Validation Error Rendering for the TextBox
As I had already mentioned in the comments you must set the Binding.Mode to BindingMode.TwoWay if you want the binding target to show validation errors.
Explanation
If only want plain property validation, then
BindingMode.OneWayToSource is sufficient. The binding engine sets
attatched properties like the Validation.Errors property on the
target element. It does this in the wake of updating the target
property. The target is only updated if the Binding.Mode is
OneWay, OneTime or TwoWay. Because you want to trigger the
data validation (which requires to update the binding source), the
only feasible mode is TwoWay.
Fix
SessionFromView.xaml
Set the Binding.Mode of the TextBox binding to BindingMode.TwoWay
<TextBox Name="SessionName"
         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{DynamicResource ValidationErrorTemplate}"
         Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />

2 Bug in ViewModelBase.ClearErrors
You missed raising the INotifyDataErrorInfo.ErrorsChanged event for the case that the parameter propertyName is null or empty.
Explanation
The binding engine subscribes to the INotifyDataErrorInfo.ErrorsChanged event to update the binding (based on the configured Binding.Mode). If you call ViewModelbase.ClearErrors without providing a property name, as you are doing, then clearing the errors will not affect the UI as the binding engine is never triggered to re-evaluate the binding that is associated with the event. As a result, the error template is not removed once the errors have been cleared.
Fix
ViewModelBase.cs
protected bool ClearErrors(string propertyName = "")
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
  {
    Errors.Clear();

    // FIX::Raise ErrrorsChanged event
    OnErrorsChanged(propertyName);

    return true;
  }

  if (Errors.Remove(propertyName))
  {
    OnErrorsChanged(propertyName);

    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

3 Validation Error Border Around Parent of TextBox
You have three possible options to fix this:

Explicitly set Binding.ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors to false (recommended).
set Validation.ErrorTemplate to null (not recommended). Although I wouldn't recommend this solution (because it will still keep the binding busy with handling validation errors, which introduces overhead and performance costs), this solution is more convenient as you can use global  implicit styles to set Validation.ErrorTemplate to {x:Null}.
Change the INotifyDataErrorInfo.GetErrors implementation (not recommended). This will eleimintae the possibility to get all errors of the binding source. WPF is using this feature heavily (which in your case causes the red border around the UserControl (or the parent hosting ContentControl to be precise).

Explanation
The default value for Binding.ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors is true. In addition, the Validation.ErrorTemplate attached property returns a default template that simply draws a red border around the target element.
If a control binds to the data source object and not to a property on this object, the binding engine passes an empty string instead of a specific property name to the INotifyDataErrorInfo.GetErrors method. If this method is implemented to return all current errors of the instance, like your ViewModelBase does (and which is the recommended implementation),
then the target has errors to display:
<!-- 
  The Content property binding targets the whole data source object 
  and not a property of the data source. As a result, the binding engine can't query the errors 
  for a particular property and instead tries to get all errors of the source object.
  And because ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors is TRUE by default, the binding on the Content property 
  will be validated.

  The following two bindings are equivalaent
-->

<ContentControl Name="NewSessionFormContentControl"
                Content="{Binding m_SessionFormViewModel}" />


<ContentControl Name="NewSessionFormContentControl"
                Content="{Binding m_SessionFormViewModel, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />

// ViewModelBase: 
// This is were all errors of the source object are returned 
// in case the binding engine passes in an empty string
public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
  => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName)
    ? Errors.SelectMany(entry => entry.Value) // Return all errors
    : Errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out IList<object> errors)
      ? (IEnumerable<object>)errors
      : new List<object>();

Fix #1 (recommended)
SessionView.xaml
<!-- Disable validation for the particular binding and avoid related overhead -->
<ContentControl Name="NewSessionFormContentControl"
                Content="{Binding m_SessionFormViewModel, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False}" />

Fix #2
SessionView.xaml
<!-- 
  Set Validation.ErrorTemplate to NULL. 
  The binding will still perform all the validation related operations
  but won't show the visual error feedback .
-->
<ContentControl Name="NewSessionFormContentControl"
                Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"
                Content="{Binding m_SessionFormViewModel}" />

Fix #3
ViewModelBase.xaml
// Don't support NULL and empty string queries
public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
  => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName)
    ? new List<object>() // Return no errors
    : Errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out IList<object> errors)
      ? (IEnumerable<object>)errors
      : new List<object>();

